# A error from a onRequestPermissionsResult

Tags: android, kotlin

recently i tried to make a download "system" but i recieve a error "Unresolved reference: STORAGE_PERMISSION_CODE"

my code :

````
        when (requestCode) {
            STORAGE_PERMISSION_CODE -> {
                if (grantResults.isNotEmpty() && grantResults[0] ==
                        PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            }
            else{
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Permission denied", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                }
        }
    }```
````

Comment: Where have you defined `STORAGE_PERMISSION_CODE` in your app?

Comment: this should be a class field final integer that you may miss.like `const val STORAGE_PERMISSION_CODE = 333`

Answer (score 0):

It appears as if you have not defined `STORAGE_PERMISSION_CODE` within the scope that in which you are testing for the storage permission being granted